# UIScrollView scrolling horizontal and vertical programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to use UIScrollView in my application, which vertically scrolls pages of individual chapter and horizontally scrolls chapters of a book/magazine. 
i can scroll vertically but how can i scroll horizontally using the same scrollview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want 2 levels of scroll view for this. I've done a similar thing and I have one scroll view which is horizontal with paging enabled and then on each of the pages there's another scroll view which is vertical also with paging enabled. I suggest you do the same.

Comment: Right, I was just going to say the same thing. There is an example in the ScrollViewSuite WWDC demo code IIRC.

Comment: on scrollview i have imageview can i use the same imageview with both scrollview or i have to use separate for each scrollview

Comment: @user1089652 Your image view would go into the 2nd level, vertical scroll view. So the layout is Horizontal `UIScrollView` -> Vertical `UIScrollView` -> `UIImageView`.